# Faulty bubble sort using recursion on slices; list does not end up sorted

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

```
def bubble_sort(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
      return
    for i in range(len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] > l[i + 1]:
            l[i], l[i + 1 ] = l[i + 1], l[i]
    bubble_sort(l[:-1])

l = [3, 2, 1]
bubble_sort(l)
print(l)
```

gives out

```
[2,1,3]
```

I'm trying to sort a list in ascending order through a recursive bubble sort. The resulting list is not a sorted one. Please ignore the indentation errors if found.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question. What is the problem?

Comment: @eozd Please check the edited question.

Comment: "Please ignore the indentation errors if found" - no, we cannot ignore them because incorrect indentation makes Python code meaningless. Please fix the indentation in your code.

Comment: @eozd: I don't think your edit was a good one; it's tantamount to putting the answer in the question.

Comment: @ruakh My rationale behind changing the title was that people with an issue regarding slices may stumble upon this question in the future. If the title is just 'faulty bubble sort', it doesn't really help anyone with a problem concerning python slicing.

Comment: @eozd: But the OP didn't *know* that (s)he had "a problem concerning python slicing", and wouldn't have asked this question if (s)he had. Someone who *knows* that they have a problem with Python slicing is not going to need this question. So you've taken a question that's useless to everyone but the OP, and made it . . . useless to everyone but the OP.

Comment: @eozd: I've now edited the title in a way that hopefully addresses your concern, while still being consistent with the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that in python, slicing operator returns a new copy of the slice, not a reference. That is if we do the following operations

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
slice = lst[2:]
slice[0] = -5
print(lst)
```

output would be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. The original list would not change. This is the problem in your code; when you pass a slice of the list to your recursion function, you don't sort the original list. A way to overcome this issue is to pass an index instead of slices. A possible solution may be as follows:

```
from random import shuffle


def bubble_sort(lst, n):
    if n == 1:
        return
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if lst[i] > lst[i+1]:
            lst[i], lst[i+1] = lst[i+1], lst[i]
    bubble_sort(lst, n - 1)


n = 50
x = [i for i in range(50)]
shuffle(x)
bubble_sort(x, n)
print(x)
```

We pass the index of the sublist to sort to our recursive function, and always do the operations on the original list without any slices. The above code should output the sorted list as expected.